# Regex to match some element text using xslt

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I am converting html content to xml. I am in situation to match the below scenario.

```
<div class="subs1">               (               <i>                l               </i>               ) “Sovereign lands” means the</div>
```

I tried the below expression

```
div[@class='subs1'][matches(.,'^&#x0a;*\s*\(\s*<i>i</i>\s*\)')]
```

but this was not working. Please someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to match `'<i>'`, but `'<i>'` is not part of the element's text. `<i>` is a child element.

I've underlined the string parts that you get when you run `match()` against `.` from the `<div>`:

```
<div class="subs1">  (  <i>  l  </i>  ) “Sovereign lands” means the</div>
                   _____   _____    _______________________________
```

If you want to ensure that there is an `<i>` child containing something specific, then you need to check for that separately.

```
div[@class='subs1' and matches(.,'^&#x0a;*\s*\(\s*i\s*\)') and i[matches(., 'i')]]
```

Comment: I need to match upto the closing brace including the <i> element
<div class="subs1">               (               <i>                l               </i>               )

Comment: @Reegan Maybe I wasn't clear enough. *You cannot match the `<i>` element.*

Comment: The that you shared is working upto div[@class='subs1' and matches(.,'^&#x0a;*\s*\(\s*i\s*\)'), but "and i[matches(., 'i')]" is not working. It showing false and I cant able to select such scenario

Comment: @Reegan Well, choose a regex that actually matches the contents of your `<i>`. In your sample XML the `<i>` contains a small 'L', the current regex can't match that.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I have used this regex 
div[@class='subs1'][matches(.,'^&#x0a;*\s*\(\s*i\s*\)')] and i[matches(normalize-space(.), 'l')]
Still the expresion is showing false

Comment: @Reegan You're closing the brackets inbetween like `][` - don't do that. My answer is not doing that either.